# What is the C++ equivalent of Python's “all” function?

Tags: python, c++, arrays

What is the C++ way of checking if all values of bool vector (or bool array) are `true`  ( do it with only 1 line like Python )

In Python, I can do

```py
a = [true, true, true, false]
b = [true, true, true]

print(all(a)) # it will print false
print(all(b)) # it will print true
```

I can do it by creating a function to check it, but I want to know if it can be done by using a built-in library.

Comment: it's std::all_of. See here for examples https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't follow. Why shouldn't there be one? Seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to want to be able to express conveniently.